# Displaying data from database with newlines using nl2br

Tags: javascript, php

I can't get it right from my previous question so I explain it here more further. 
This is my index.php and that's the method I used to save it to database

```
<html>

<head>

<script>

function updategroup()
{
var update_con=document.getElementsByName("update_con")[0].value.replace(/\\r\\n/g, "<br />");
var xmlhttp;
if(update_con == "" || update_con == " ")
{
    alert("Box is empty");
    return;
}
else{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("groups").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET","fors.php?update_con="+update_con,true);
xmlhttp.send();}
}

</script>

</head>


<body>
<textarea name="update_con" rows="5" cols="50" >
</textarea>

<button onclick="updategroup()" >click</button>
<div id="groups" ><?php include("updates.php"); ?></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The line

> var update_con=document.getElementsByName("update_con")[0].value.replace(/\r\n/g, "
> ");

I used to replace nl to br. Am I get it right? I guess not.

this is the fors.php

```
<?php

include("conn2.php");

$update_con = $_GET["update_con"];

$query_fors = "INSERT INTO updates(update_con) VALUES('$update_con')";
mysql_query($query_fors);

include("updates.php");

?>
```

And finally, my updates.php

```
<?php

include("conn2.php");

$query_sel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM updates");
while($rows_sel = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_sel)){
$update_con = $rows_sel['update_con'];

//echo "<div style='border: 1px solid #000;' >$update_con</div><br />";
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($update_con))."<br />";
}

?>
```

I used the line `echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($update_con))` for displaying it. And when I enter texts inside the textarea with newlines, I only get a straight texts,without breaks,without newlines.... And when I open 'updates' table inside 'fors' database. I couldn't see texts with newlines like I enter into textarea. Thanks in advance :)
I don't want my database to hold any html tags :)

Comment: http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br/

Comment: why this: `.replace(/\r\n/g, " ");` - that's what's killing your breaks. just send `encodeURIComponent(update_con)`

Comment: Wow!!! It works!!! That's what I want to know...Thanks sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why this: .replace(/\r\n/g, " "); - that's what's killing your breaks. just send encodeURIComponent(update_con) - [Kai Qing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461186/kai-qing)